# C# XML ModelBinding - ASP.NET Core 8 Web API - required field not found

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core-webapi, model-binding, .net-8.0

I want to bind this XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<D:propfind xmlns:D='DAV:' xmlns:A='http://apple.com/ns/ical/'
    xmlns:C='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav'>
    <D:prop>
        <D:resourcetype />
        <D:owner />
        <D:displayname />
        <D:current-user-principal />
        <D:current-user-privilege-set />
        <A:calendar-color />
        <C:calendar-home-set />
    </D:prop>
</D:propfind>
```

to XML objects:

```
[XmlRoot("propfind", Namespace = DavNamepaces.davXmlNamespace)]
public class PropFindRequest()
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "prop", Namespace = DavNamepaces.davXmlNamespace)]
    public Properties Properties { get; set; } = null!;
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="prop")]
public class Properties
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="resourcetype")] 
    public object Resourcetype { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="owner")] 
    public object Owner { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="displayname")] 
    public object Displayname { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="current-user-principal")] 
    public object Currentuserprincipal { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="current-user-privilege-set")] 
    public object Currentuserprivilegeset { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="calendar-color")] 
    public object Calendarcolor { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="calendar-home-set")] 
    public object Calendarhomeset { get; set; } 
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services
       .AddControllers(options =>
                {
                    options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter>();
                    options.InputFormatters.RemoveType<SystemTextJsonInputFormatter>();
                })
// Adds builder.AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters(); && builder.AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
       .AddXmlFormaterExtensions();
```

Controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("caldav/")]
public class CalDavController
{
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)]
    [Produces("application/xml")]
    [Consumes("application/xml")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Propfind([FromXmlBody(XmlSerializerType = XmlSerializerType.XmlSerializer)]PropFindRequest propFindRequest,[FromHeader] int Depth)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Error:

> Error: Bad Request
> Response body
> Download
> 400
>
> One or more validation errors occurred.  
> https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1  
> 00-e1611d29682cd7e995d256c79850082d-ebfcd416977a94a7-00  
>   
> An error occurred while deserializing input data.  
> The propFindRequest field is required.

I was expecting that the mapping works with the annotations I added.

I tried first to change the `Request` just to match the expectations in the `Response`

Trial and error request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<propFindRequest>
    <properties>
        <resourcetype>string</resourcetype>
        <owner>string</owner>
        <displayname>string</displayname>
        <currentuserprincipal>string</currentuserprincipal>
        <currentuserprivilegeset>string</currentuserprivilegeset>
        <calendarcolor>string</calendarcolor>
        <calendarhomeset>string</calendarhomeset>
    </properties>
</propFindRequest>
```

but it resulted in the same error, therefore I think I made a mistake but I have no clue where.

Am I missing something important?

Do I have to use `DataContractSerializer`? I thought that this should work out of the box with the default `XmlSerializer` according to MS.

Comment: Either one of two things are happening 1) The Controller/Server is not getting hte entire XML file in the body 2) The class definition in the server is not the same as the client.  Every time you update the class definition you must update both the client and server.